# I can't get the input of the arraylist in java why?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, arraylist, runtime-error, linkedhashset

I have one problem in List and LinkedHashSet in java

```
// Java Program

import java.util.*;

public class always_edit_this {
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int r = sc.nextInt();
        List<String> a = Arrays.asList(sc.nextLine().split(" "));
        LinkedHashSet <String> ans = new LinkedHashSet<>(a);
        System.out.println(ans);

    }

}
```

// In the above program

I can get the integer value input but,
After getting that It terminates the program and
Don't get a List input
I don't know why anybody can solve this

Does any anybody can solve this